# How to use AcceptTcpClient in asynchronous method

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tcp, c++-cli

I am making a small program using C++/CLI that use `TcpListener`, I know that `AcceptTcpClient` is a synchronous method, which blocking UI thread. How can I call this method so that it won't block my UI? Here is my code:

```
TcpClient^ client = server->AcceptTcpClient();
sendConsoleResult( "Connected to Client, waiting for for instructions..." );
data = nullptr;
// Get a stream Object* for reading and writing
NetworkStream^ stream = client->GetStream();
Int32 i;
// Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
while ( i = stream->Read( bytes, 0, bytes->Length ))
{
    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII String*.
    data = Encoding::ASCII->GetString( bytes, 0, i );
    sendConsoleResult("[RECEIVED]: "+ data);
    // Process the data then send to command processing module
    data = data->ToUpper();
    response = commandProcess(data)->ToUpper();
    array<Byte>^msg = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes( response );
    // Send back a response.
    stream->Write( msg, 0, msg->Length );
    sendConsoleResult("[RESPONSE]: " + response);
}
```

Thank you for answering my question:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to using [TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient.aspx), as well as using [NetworkStream.BeginRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread.aspx).  This will make your entire operation asynchronous, and not block your user interface thread.